# Angular - multiple keywords in search bar - how to exclude search results which doesnt match each keyword?

Tags: angularjs, filter, get

I have a search field where I want to display products based on the keyword(s). So far products are being shown which match EITHER one of the keywords but I want the search results displayed ONLY when ALL keywords are matched. I tried to do a for loop through the arguments (the input /keywords)and used angulars filter but its not really working. Any ideas?

```
var app=angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('appController', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.search = function(key) {
            function listOfItems(key) {
                var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                var keywords = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    keywords += array[i] + '+'
                }
                return keywords.slice(0, keywords.length - 1);
            }
            $scope.parameter = listOfItems(key);


            $http.('http://example.com/store/?keyword=' + $scope.parameter + '&token=11111111.22222')
                .then(function(prods) {
                  return prods.data;
                   if($scope.parameter){                        
                    $scope.prods = prods.data;
                   }
                })
        }
    })
```

html:

```
<input ng-model="key" type="text" class="form-control>                         
   <button type=" submit " ng-click="search(key) ">
</button>
<div ng-repeat="shop in shops | filter: search(key) ">
   <p>{{shop.title}}</p>
   <p>{{shop.description}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you mind to provide minimal working plnkr/jsbin/jsfiddle ?